# Fitnesse Git Plugin ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, fitnesse

I've followed the guide to install this [fitnesse-git-plugin](https://github.com/fitnesse/fitnesse-git-plugin) for [fitnesse](https://github.com/fitnesse/fitnesse) and I'm getting a class not found error. When I run `java -jar fitnesse-standalone.jar` I get the following output

```
SEVERE: Error while starting the FitNesse [Unable to instantiate component for type fitnesse.wiki.fs.FileSystemPageFactory]
fitnesse.components.ComponentInstantiationException: Unable to instantiate component for type fitnesse.wiki.fs.FileSystemPageFactory
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:81)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:57)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:100)
    at fitnesse.ContextConfigurator.makeFitNesseContext(ContextConfigurator.java:106)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:72)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.launchFitNesse(FitNesseMain.java:59)
    at fitnesseMain.FitNesseMain.main(FitNesseMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:75)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: fitnesse.components.ComponentInstantiationException: Unable to look up component for type 'VersionsController' with classname 'fitnesse.wiki.fs.GitFileVersionsController'
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:53)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:100)
    at fitnesse.wiki.fs.FileSystemPageFactory.<init>(FileSystemPageFactory.java:36)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fitnesse.wiki.fs.GitFileVersionsController
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.lookupComponentClass(ComponentFactory.java:96)
    at fitnesse.components.ComponentFactory.createComponent(ComponentFactory.java:49)
    ... 13 more
```

Here is my directory structure,

```
.
├── FitNesseRoot
├── fitnesse-standalone.jar
├── plugins
│   └── fitnesse-git-plugin-1.2.0-all.jar
└── plugins.properties
```

can the contents of my plugins.properties

```
VersionsController=fitnesse.wiki.fs.GitFileVersionsController 
RecentChanges=fitnesse.wiki.fs.GitFileVersionsController
```

This is how the guide says to install the plugin, but keeps failing. Is it something to do with my classpath?

Comment: Which version of FitNesse are you using?

Comment: Most recent 20180127 http://fitnesse.org/.FrontPage.FitNesseDevelopment.FitNesseRelease20180127